# Net Core C# - Connect to graph via proxy AAD SSO

Tags: asp.net-core, graph, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a Net Core wep app , hosted within our walled garden , which authenticates to Azure AD using non-interative single sign on (OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).

Unfortuantely, all our outbound traffic goes through a web proxy. Im able to get the AAD authentication part to work fine, using the following in my Program.cs :

```
  builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            options => {
                options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler() {
                    UseProxy = true,
                    Proxy = aadProxy,
                    PreAuthenticate = true,
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }
                };
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };
            });
```

and the user is able to authenticate fine.

Now my problem is getting the Graph SDK to connect via the proxy. I have tried using some of the solutions already posted here, but none of the seem to work :(

the closest i have managed to get to is :

```
            HttpClient httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(authCodeCredential, "v1.0", "Global", msalFactory.GetWebProxy());
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
```

while setting up the GraphServiceClient , however, condidering our set-up (SSO , non -interactive), what type of credential am i meant to supply? Ive seen a solution that involves setting up :

```
var clientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication(...)
```

but ConfidentialClientApplication appears to be deprecated and the examples online appear to pass in  3 or four parameters, while the version i have (sdk v4) only support 2.

has anyone actually managed to solve this problem because it is driving me up the wall?!

If ConfidentialClientApplication has been deprecated, what am i meant to use instead, that still provides options to pass traffic via a proxy?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried a number of solutions on stack, which work fine locally on my development machine, but just result in a timeout on my deployment server. The firewall is fine, and AAD authentication works perfectly. But im unable to configure graph to use a proxy.